# Recorrer una lista con la interfaz iterable

Tags: java

Hola tengo una duda con la interfaz iterable de java, no sabría muy bien como funciona esta interfaz y como podría implementarla para que me recorra dos listas que tengo definidas en el main. Al ser una interfaz podría pasarle desde el main las dos listas y desde la interfaz recorrer ambas y devolverlas al main ¿?

Por ejemplo tengo esto en el main:

```
List<Integer> lis1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> lis2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

lis1 = formarLista(lis1);
lis2 = formarLista(lis2);

public static List<Integer> formarLista(List<Integer> lista) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        lista.add(i);   
    }
    return lista;
}
```

y despues les voy metiendo 10 números, ¿como implemento la interfaz iterable desde el main? y como haría para pasarle ambas listas a la interfaz iterable y que las recorra y el resultado pasarlo al main? Gracias

Comment: Sería cuestión de pasar las dos listas a `formarLista()`, para lo cual el método debería definirse así: `public static List<Integer> formarLista(List<Integer> lista1, List<Integer> lista2) {` Luego trabajas las dos listas y devuelves una sola lista o lo que quieras después de operar con los dos objetos. En el `main` harías algo así: `List<Integer> listaFinal = formarLista(lis1, lis2);` Ahí tendrías en el contexto del `main` lo que devolvió el método. No sé si es eso lo que quieres, porque la pregunta no es muy clara que digamos.

Answer (score 0):

De lo que entendí de tu pregunta hice un método que recibe dos listas y que retorne otra lista con todos los enteros de las listas pasadas por parámetro:

```
public List<Integer> recorrerListas(List<Integer> lista1, List<Integer> lista2) {
    List<Integer> aRetornar = new ArrayList<Integer>();

//Recorre toda la lista1 y agrega los elementos a la lista a retornar
        for(Integer entero : lista1) { 
            aRetornar.add(entero);
        }

//Recorre toda la lista2 y agrega los elementos a la lista a retornar
        for(Integer entero : lista2) { 
            aRetornar.add(entero);
        }

        return aRetornar;
}
```